# Develop for Windows (in C) from Linux/OS X or Unix

Tags: c, windows, vim, emacs, cross-platform

I am used to the development tool and process in unix environment. Recently I need to develop an application for Windows. So I am wondering if it is possible to setup a virtual environment mimicking Windows SDK so that my tools (Emacs, Vim, etc.) can employ compilers or syntax checkers to process the header files (mainly in C) correctly when I am writing the code. As it is, if I merely copy the windows SDK headers to my local environment, there are lot of OS checking errors that I cant' get rid of.

I have learnt of Winetricks lately. But I don't really understand it and don't how to use it on my purpose. I mainly need it to help me write code more efficiently. But if it can also facilitate my debugging process, that'll be wonderful.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, that is develop for linux from Windows... The thing is, I know nothing about developing in Windows...

Comment: It's probably much less of a hassle to use MS Visual Studio.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't know how to use that either... I don't even have that...

Comment: Well then [get it](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). But if you have never programmed for Windows there is quite some learning curve anyway.

Comment: My recommendation: Try to make your Windows environment as "Unix-y" as possible (install Cygwin, Vim, etc.) and work with that. (You can still use Visual Studio in parallel.) Trying to develop on Unix will be difficult / impossible. For one, the backslashes used in Windows paths will wreak havoc on a pure Unix toolchain.

Comment: MinGW can cross-compile from Linux ... though testing the software would still be a bit of a pain. Honestly, I'd avoid Visual Studio for C dev (one can uses MSYS2 or something instead).

Comment: Is it a gui or chui interface you are developing?  If it is a gui, try using some multi-platform library like FLTK, wxWidgets or Qt (read conditions first if you wish to use it commercially).  That way, it doesn't matter which platform you use.

Comment: @cup it's Cui I am developing. Just the API provided to me is only support Windows among the platforms we are working on. So I was wondering if there is a way to stay in UNIX like environment. If possible I really don't want to go down Windows that hell hole again...

Comment: If you develop for multiple platforms at once, install and use a mingw cross-compilation toolchain, and make a makefile "win" target that builds with that toolchain. At first, only compile and debug for Unix, from Unix, then try to compile the "win" target, fixing errors by conditionally changing headers and API calls with their windows API/SDK equivalent. When you have no compile errors in any makefile target, and no runtime errors in Unix, only then start debugging the Windows part - you could probably use Wine and a mingw-ported GDB for that. At the end, test on a "real"/virtual Win machine

Comment: If you just use Visual Studio - it is like using emacs, eclipse or codeblocks.  You just stay in the tool all day,